# Email Script running on Google Form Responses - I cannot turn it off?

Tags: forms, google-spreadsheets

So here's my predicament:

1. I created a Google Form
2. I put a script on the Responses to email the results that were entered that day to another email. Easy
3. To do the email every day, I added a google script trigger.
4. I removed the sheet the other day, since I was unable to transfer the setup to my company domain (also on Google).
5. The Form, Sheet and Script are all gone, BUT IT STILL EMAILS EVERY DAY!

Where can I find the script to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it by meself.

1. Open any sheet on Google sheet.
2. Then go to Tools -> Script editor.
3. It will create a new project
4. Save it as anything (you cant do anything if you don't save)
5. Go to Resources -> All my triggers
6. Delete the legacy trigger.